# PHP - in_array doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, arrays, function

Although I'm fairly experienced with PHP, I recently meet with this issue which driving me nuts.

```
    <?PHP
// This code is just basic example
$we_need = array(
    'Carrot',
    'Onion',
    'Milk',
    'Onion',
    'Potato'
); // Notice that Onion is on two places
$basket  = array(); // An empty basket
foreach ($we_need as $product) {
    // Add product to basket ONLY if it's not already there
    if (!in_array($product, $basket)) {
        $basket[] = $product;
    } else {
        echo "For debugging: Duplicate detected, so skipped.\n";
    }
}
print_r($basket);
?>
```

What is wrong with this code? Why $basket array have duplicates at the end?
In my real program, $we_need is fetched from database, but it isn't multidimensional array nor new lines in values.

I know that I can use array_unique() for this approach, but I want to know where the problem is?

Comment: Theres a } missing for the foreach loop

Comment: `in_array()` or `is_array()`?

Comment: So _fairly experienced with PHP_, huh?!!

Comment: i don't know if _you want to know where the problem is?_

Comment: I want to known, and don't say it's missing braces, because it isn't, Original code is perfectly fine and doesn't work. I'm concerned that problem is with PHP on my server?

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine: http://3v4l.org/2ZJ8p

Comment: Then problem must be with my PHP installation. Thank you for testing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a closing bracket missing.

```
foreach ($we_need as $product) {

    // Add product to basket ONLY if it's not already there
    if (!in_array($product, $basket)) {
        $basket[] = $product;
    } else {
        echo "For debugging: Duplicate detected, so skipped.\n";
    } // <<<------- here
}
```

Then you get:

```
For debugging: Duplicate detected, so skipped. 
Array ( [0] => Carrot [1] => Onion [2] => Milk [3] => Potato )
```

Comment: That would be the answer, if missing bracket really missing in my original code.

Comment: Thank you for testing it out. It seems that code works for everyone except me, so I conclude that problems must lay in PHP installation on my server. 
Your answer doesn't fix the issue, and it doesn't have, but will help others to see working version of the code and my comment as well, if nothing help.